# Trying to replace html tags using regex

Tags: javascript, replace, element

For the example, I'm trying to replace

```
<script type='text/javascript'>some stuff</script>
```

with:

```
<div type='text/javascript'>some stuff</div>
```

I'm currently testing with:

```
alert( o.replace( /(?:<\s*\/?\s*)(script)(?:\s*([^>]*)?\s*>)/gi ,'div') );
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
divsomestuffdiv
```

How can I get this to only replace the "script" portion and preserve the other markup and attribute characters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have keep the opening and closing tag brackets. So try this:

```
o.replace(/(<\s*\/?\s*)script(\s*([^>]*)?\s*>)/gi ,'$1div$2')
```

Answer (score 2):

DOM methods are better suited for this than regular expressions. This way you'll manipulate your document logically instead of as plaintext:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = 0, el; el = els[i]; i++) {
    var new = document.createElement('div');
    new.type = el.type;
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(el, new);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A naive but readable way would be to do it in two passes i suppose and first match and replace the

> `<script`

part with

> `<div`

and then another which would match

> `</script>`

and replace it with

> `</div>`